# Flutter Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version. Error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a Windows application with Flutter. After running the application I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
Unable to load the service index for source https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe.
  The content at 'https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe' is not a valid JSON object.
  Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/permission_handler_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:29 (message):
  Failed to install nuget package Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.210806.1
```

And the app closes before it even opens. How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.